# IOS flutter Developer Mode was on but failed to build

Tags: ios, flutter

I connect my iPhone to my mac, building my flutter app. I turned on my Developer Mode, but when I build it, it aborted saying I need to turn on Developer mode, although it was already on. Anyone has seen this issue before? Thank you!

I tried re connecting the device, restarting VS Code, re-turned on developer mode, none worked.

Comment: Open your project in Xcode and build from there. It will tell you if there is a problem with connecting to your phone and make sure it is prepared properly